# Map x-www-form-urlencoded data to Firehose format in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis-firehose, vtl, x-www-form-urlencoded

Based on docs, forum post etc, I came up with this solution to first transform the url encoded form post data into a variable and then base64 encode it before sending to Firehose (firehose needs the payload to be in this format)

```
#set($data = {})
#foreach( $token in $input.path('$').split('&') )
    #set( $keyVal = $token.split('=') )
    #set( $keyValSize = $keyVal.size() )
    #if( $keyValSize >= 1 )
        #set( $key = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[0]) )
        #if( $keyValSize >= 2 )
            #set( $val = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[1]) )
        #else
            #set( $val = '' )
        #end
    #end
    $util.qr($data.put("$key", "$val"))
#end

{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "my-firehose",
    "Record": { 
        "Data": "$util.base64encode($data)"
    },
    "PartitionKey": "1"
}
```

However, the result after transformation is

```
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "my-firehose",
    "Record": {
        "Data": ""
    },
    "PartitionKey": "1"
}
```

I have tried various permutations of `$util.qr($data.put("$key", "$val"))` but none seem to work

- `$util.qr($data.put("$key", $val))`
- `$util.qr($data.put("$key", $util.parseJson($val)))`
- `$util.qr($data.put("$key", $util.toJson($util.parseJson($val))))`
- `$util.qr($data.put("$key", "abc"))  // hardcoded just to debug`

But all of them result in an empty `Data` block in the final output.

And this one doesn't even transform (throws a 500)

```
#set($data = {
    #foreach( $token in $input.path('$').split('&') )
        #set( $keyVal = $token.split('=') )
        #set( $keyValSize = $keyVal.size() )
        #if( $keyValSize >= 1 )
            #set( $key = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[0]) )
            #if( $keyValSize >= 2 )
                #set( $val = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[1]) )
            #else
                #set( $val = '' )
            #end
        #end
        "$key": "$val" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
})
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "my-firehose",
    "Record": { 
        "Data": "$util.base64encode($data)"
    },
    "PartitionKey": "1"
}
```

What am I messing up?

**Updates**

Based on @michael-sqlbot's pointers, I did find the magic recipe (not the full recipe though)

```
#set($data = {})
    #foreach( $token in $input.path('$').split('&') )
        #set( $keyVal = $token.split('=') )
        #set( $keyValSize = $keyVal.size() )
        #if( $keyValSize >= 1 )
            #set( $key = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[0]) )
            #if( $keyValSize >= 2 )
                #set( $val = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[1]) )
            #else
                #set( $val = '' )
            #end
        #end
        $!data.put("$key", "$util.parseJson($val)")
    #end

{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "my-firehose",
    "Record": { 
        "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)"
    },
    "PartitionKey": "1"
}
```

Also, `base64encode` needs to be `base64Encode`. With those changes, I'm seeing the data flowing through. Only issue remaining is that it's not exactly JSON:

```
"data": "{abc={user_info={session_id=}, event_id=77841543625, date_time=2019-12-16T21:26:17.911Z}, sb=, hello=world}"
```

It's also not quoting strings properly so maybe there's some more figuring out to do.

Comment: What's `$util.qr()`?  I don't see it [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference).

Comment: Hmm, it's not documented in there. But it's documented under AppSync docs. You might be on to something. If that documentation is the only supported set, then util.toJson is also not available. However, it should support VTL by that accord since it is [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html), right?

Comment: `$util.qr()` is [quiet reference](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#quiet-reference-notation) helper. In Velocity, you can do it via `$!data.put` or the long form of `$!{data.put...}`. API docs link to VTL 2.0 [reference](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/vtl-reference.html) which seems to be a subset of [2.0 user guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html). If that subset is the only thing they support, then this can't be done in mapping. Would need to go thru a lambda or something.

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of nudge from Michael - sqlbot to set me in the right direction, so thanks for that.

A few things were not quite correct in my initial approach:

- API Gateway has a smaller set of helpers than something like AppSync. It only supports the methods that are documented here: [API Gateway WebSocket API Mapping Template Reference](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-mapping-template-reference.html)
- Somewhere buried in there is also the reference to [Apache Velocity Template Language (VTL)](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html) which takes you to the reference page for Velocity Template Language.
- VTL doc encourages you to check out its [User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html) and it is not immediately clear if AWS supports just the language or the Engine. The answer, after a LOT of trial & error, is that it supports a mix.
- Bad news is that I cannot use things like `util.qr` or `util.toJson` but for my purposes, I was able to hack together a solution that works for my goals.
- Velocity Objects/Map is not same as JavaScript objects. When you use `$myVar.put(...)` you get an  object that serializes to something like `{ key=Value, deepKey={nestedKey=nestedValue}`. It is identical to a JS object if you substitute the `=` sign with `:`. In order to make it like JSON, you'd also have to properly quote the keys and values. As you can imagine, this can get ugly very quick.

I was pretty close to abandoning this approach and use a lambda which can do the transforms and write records to Firehose instead but my url encoded data was JSON underneath which helped in this case.

So without further ado, here's the solution that worked for me:

```
#set($data = "")

## parse through url encoded data, split into kv pairs
#foreach( $token in $input.path('$').split('&') )
    #set( $keyVal = $token.split('=') )
    #set( $keyValSize = $keyVal.size() )
    #if( $keyValSize >= 1 )
        #set( $key = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[0]) )
        #if( $keyValSize >= 2 )
            #set( $val = $util.urlDecode($keyVal[1]) )
        #else
            #set( $val = '' )
        #end
    #end

    ## append to stringified JSON string
    #set($data = "${data}\""${key}\"":$util.escapeJavaScript($val)#if($foreach.hasNext),#end")
#end

#set($data = "$data.replaceAll('\\', '')}
")
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "my-firehose",
    "Record": { 
        "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)"
    },
    "PartitionKey": "1"
}
```

**Explanation**

Due to limitations mentioned above, I abandoned my earlier approach and instead decided to create the stringified JSON myself. That is being done here.

In order to get a proper string that can be serialized, you'd have to escape the double quotes - `$util.escapeJavaScript($val)` does exactly that.

```
#set($data = "${data}\""${key}\"":$util.escapeJavaScript($val)#if($foreach.hasNext),#end")
```

You'd have to wrap the `key` in double quotes and escape them as well otherwise the resulting string would be incorrect. `\""${key}\""` does that. Figuring out how escape `\"` took me a few more tries since AWS doesn't support [Velocity Escape Tool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html). The correct sequence is double double quotes (to escape the double quotes within the expression) and a single slash (code highlighting will indicate a broken string expression so I tried with `\\` but turned out the syntax highlighting was wrong. Just a single slash works fine). This will result in a string like this:

```
"{\"abc\":{\"user_info\":{\"session_id\":\"\"},\"event_id\":\"77841543625\",\"date_time\":\"2019-12-16T21:26:17.911Z\",\"sb\":1,\"hello\":\"world\"}"
```

Next, I remove the slashes from the final JSON, add the wrapping braces and add a newline to each record:

```
#set($data = "{$data.replaceAll('\\', '')}  // <- wrapping braces and slash removal
")     // <- this is newline adding block, not a typo
```

Finally, the Firehose payload is what gets emitted:

```
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "my-firehose",
    "Record": { 
        "Data": "$util.base64Encode($data)"
    },
    "PartitionKey": "1"
}
```

This results in records like this to the final destination:

```
{"abc":{"user_info":{"session_id": ""}, "event_id": "77841543625", "date_time":"2019-12-16T21:26:17.911Z"}, "sb": 1, "id": "home"}
{"abc":{"user_info":{"session_id": ""}, "event_id": "84154343625", "date_time":"2019-12-16T22:31:43.543Z"}, "sb": 1, "id": "sub"}
...
```